# Dart error using Flutter in VSCode keeps cropping up

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Using Flutter in Visual Studio Code, the following error-message window keeps cropping up.

Why ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an syntax error somewhere that keeps crashing the dart analyzer. I once had this problem because i wrote a constructor like this:

```
MyClass(this.myparam) : super[myparam];
```

Since its the dart analysis server who should tell you about erros like this it's hard to notice (since it crashes trying to understand whats wrong)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to find the error... Too bad the dart-analysis does not pinpoint the mistake more clearly. It will  be very hard to find... But again, thanks !

Comment: I noticed that your error says FileSystemException while mine was Unsupported operation: unsupported initializer. So the actual reason may be something else (some file permission problems for example)

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting this issue:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36919

Flutter is generating recursive symlinks and the analysis server follows them like any other directory, so gets stuck in an endless tree. It's not clear which side it'll be fixed, but you can subscribe to that GH issue for updates.